# Como adicionar um novo nó em um XML com jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml

Como eu posso adicionar, com jQuery, um novo nó `<nota ordem="4">` com os nós padrões que estão no exemplo que estou mostrando no arquivo XML abaixo (nome,data,unidade,referencia e texto)?

Eu queria acrescentar depois do nota ordem 3 um nota ordem 4.

arquivo XML:

```
<nota ordem="1">
    <nome>Leonardo</nome>
    <data>07/12/2015</data>
    <unidade>Ensino Médio</unidade>
    <referencia>Este um titulo de conteúdo de teste</referencia>
    <texto>Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste.</texto>
</nota>

<nota ordem="2">
    <nome>Marcela</nome>
    <data>08/12/2015</data>
    <unidade>Ensino Médio</unidade>
    <referencia>Este um titulo de conteúdo de teste</referencia>
    <texto>Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste.</texto>
</nota>

<nota ordem="3">
    <nome>Rafaela</nome>
    <data>09/12/2015</data>
    <unidade>Ensino Médio</unidade>
    <referencia>Este um titulo de conteúdo de teste</referencia>
    <texto>Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste--Conteúdo de teste.</texto>
</nota>
```

OBS: Não está aparecendo ai, mas os nós que tem o nome de nota estão envolvidos por um nó chamado `todas_notas`

Comment: Olá @LeonardoMonteiro, seja bem vindo a SOpt. Você pode organizar a sua dúvida para que possamos ajudá-lo. Está muito confuso e você pode ter vários votos negativos. O que você deseja fazer realmente? Separe os dados que você quer adicionar com Jquery. E antes de tudo, faça o tour do SOpt http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Eu editei minha dúvida você poderia visualizar para ver se consegui ser mais claro? obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Com jQuery você teria que fazer assim:

```
var $node = $('<nota/>', {
    ordem : 4,
    html: [
        $('<nome/>', {html: 'Hugo'}),
        $('<data />', {html: '10/05/2001'}),
        // E assim por diante
    ]
})
```

Como você citou que o elemento pai do seu `xml` é `todas_notas`, então faça assim:

```
$('todas_notas').append($node)
```

Para você ver como os dados do nó `nota` que foi criado, fiz um snippet:

```js
$(function(){
    var $node = $('<nota/>', {
     ordem : 4,
     html: [
      $('<nome/>', {html: 'Hugo'}),
      $('<data />', {html: '10/05/2001'}),
     ]
    })


    html_of_node = $node.prop('outerHTML');

    $('body').text(html_of_node)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Wallace